# How do you insert into mongoDB with specific data type in Perl?

Tags: perl, mongodb

In MySQL for example you have data types such as varchar, int, etc.
I googled and found http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#bson-types page. It seems like with string you just use '' or "". Integers seem to be automatically recognized without specifing the type. How would inserting something like this into mongoDB collection in Perl look like?

```
Example:
{
 "Name" : "John"
 "Age" :   20
 "Weight" : 180.5
 "Dateofbirth" : 01/01/1990
}
```

The reason why I want data type specified in the db is that I can use operators to compare numbers for example. If it is text I cannot do that.
So far I am thinking in Perl:

```
$my_collection->insert({
                        'Name' : "$Name",
                        'Age'  : $age,
                         'Weight':$weight,
                         'Dateofbirth': $datevar, 
                       } );
```

In the above code I am not sure how to specify the data type. For example to tell Weight is Double not integer or string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For numeric types, the Perl MongoDB driver will go by whatever Perl thinks the number is. Perl has an internal flag for keeping track of whether something is a float or an int. The MongoDB driver will use 32 or 64-bit ints depending on your platform. If it looks like a string to Perl, it will be stored as a string in MongoDB.

For date types, you need to wrap the date in a [DateTime](http://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) object, or [DateTime::Tiny](http://metacpan.org/module/DateTime%3a%3aTiny) if you use the `dt_type` attribute.

Comment: so it makes no difference how I use "$age" vs $age in $my_collection->insert statement? I was thinking that is how MongoDB driver knows to treat the field as string or number by that double or single quotes.

Comment: Perl could think the number is a string. For JSON encoding, I have a habit of always adding "0" to a number first.

Comment: @DoodleKana, the MongoDB driver doesn't know about whether you used double quotes or not. It just gets an `*SV` (scalar value) structure, and uses the Perl API to find out if Perl thinks it's a string or a number.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a full answer - for example, if a person had a `Weight` of 180 instead of 180.5, I see no way to coerce it to a float (`SvNOK`) except adding `1e-50` to it or something.

Comment: @KenWilliams, yes, sadly forcing an `IV` or `PV` to `NV` is rather difficult. I don't know of a good or idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: It might be worth adding functions to `MongoDB` that expose the `SvNOK_only()` and `SvPOK_only_UTF8()` XS macros.  I can add a ticket on github if you want.

Comment: @KenWilliams, it's a good idea. Can you do me a favor and add a ticket [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PERL)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the looks_like_number parameter in the Perl MongoDB driver

use MongoDB::BSON
$MongoDB::BSON::looks_like_number = 1;

https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::BSON#looks_like_number